# ¿Como puedo modificar el tamaño de un arreglo de acuerdo a un clic de mi boton?

Tags: android

lo que me gustaria es hacer que mi arreglo vaya creciendo conforme voy haciendo clic en diferentes botones y ya lo hacer pero como creo nuevos objetos de tipo arreglo pues los valores que tomaba con anterioridad los elimina y solo puedo obtener los valores recientes.

Forma actual de realizar la accion

```
   numeros=new int[conta];

    numeros[conta-1]=Integer.parseInt(botonesT);
```

Resultado de la forma actual

```
000006
```

Se supone que el resultado debería ser `9748362` y la cuestión es que como puedo modificar un solo arreglo en cuanto a su tamaño sin la necesidad de crear uno nuevo.

Forma de concatenar mi arreglo

```
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int value : numeros) {
        builder.append(value);
    }
    String textoJunto = builder.toString();
```

Comment: **No se puede cambiar el tamaño** del `array` ,  su tamaño es fijo , si desea una estructura de capacidad dinámica una opción son `Listas` . como lo menciona @Einer en su respuesta.

Comment: Esto que comenta Dev. Joel ya se había preguntado hace tiempo, no se si se cerro la pregunta o ya fue eliminada, ya que no la encontré.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es obligatorio tener que crear una nueva instancia del array para aumentar la capacidad de indices. Por esa razón se crearon las listas donde puedes agregar cuantos elementos desees:

```
ArrayList<String> nombres = new ArrayList<>();
nombres.add("einer");
nombres.add("pablo");
nombres.add("marcos");
nombres.add("juan");
int tamano = nombres.size(); // 4
```

Comment: creo que valdría la pena recalcarle al OP que no sólo los `ArrayList` permiten ese tipo de operaciones. En el comentario pusiste `//5` pero sólo agregaste 4 elementos, y tomando en cuenta que es **android**, desconozco si `System.out.println` funciona ahí. de ahí en más, +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Como puedo modificar el tamaño de un arreglo?

Es muy importante definir que **no se puede modificar el tamaño de un Array**.

> la cuestión es que como puedo modificar un solo arreglo en cuanto a
>   su tamaño sin la necesidad de crear uno nuevo.

No puedes modificar el tamaño, no es permitido redimensionar tu Array, en este caso es necesario crear uno nuevo.